# Regex Python - Keep only ASCII and copyright symbol

Tags: python, regex

I have the following function to keep only ASCII characters:

```
import re

def remove_special_chars(txt):
    txt = re.sub(r'[^\x00-\x7F]+', '', txt)
    return txt
```

But now I also want to keep the copyright symbol (©). What should I add to the pattern?

Comment: The copyright symbol is `Dec: 169 Hex: A9`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add the copyright symbol's hex `\xA9` ([source](https://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm)) to your match group:

```
txt = re.sub(r'[^\x00-\x7F\xA9]+', '', txt)
```

[<sup>Regex101</sup>](https://regex101.com/r/QHidO1/1)

Answer (score 0):

From Python3.8 onwards Unicode character name may be [used in regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3.8/whatsnew/3.8.html#other-language-changes) via `\N{name}` escapes.

So copyright symbol may be used like `r'\N{COPYRIGHT SIGN}'`.

In your case,

```
import re
s = "Python® Copyright ©2001-2019"
re.sub(r'[^\x00-\x7F\N{COPYRIGHT SIGN}]+', '', s)
```

This gives

```
'Python Copyright ©2001-2019'
```

As you can see, the '®' was removed.